# Best practices to create a test automation solution on mobile app in IoT?

Tags: mobile-automation

I'm approaching to create the test automation architecture for a mobile project for the first time.
Here are the issues:
-The project if (of course) multi platform (all Android devices running version 8 or higher and all iOS devices running iOS 12 or higher)
-Both apps are natives (Android Studio/Kotlin + Xcode/Swift)
-The app has a core BT library because the software communicates via BT with a phisycal object (IoT)

- The server used to trigger a system of alarm via certains codes is on Firebase
- The server used to manage communications to end users and that translate the codes from Firebase is on AWS
  -The project is already in production as I was hired by this company 6 months ago
  -The company asked me to try to create a TAA for this project

My idea is to start with some unit tests (for all the functions and library used for both Android and iOS),then make some integration testing via API but.. I have no idea if it's possibile to automate some interactions between the app, the BT and the alarm to trigger.
Do you know if there is a "best practice" to automate mobile app in the context of IoT?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are trying to initiate a test automation solution on the mobile app in IoT, make sure you understand these basic requirements:

1. The IoT based application is multi-user and is usually deployed in a dispersed environment
2. The active application should offer a good response time
3. Make sure proper data validation occurs throughout the application
4. How does the application expand? The internet or locally?
5. Make sure the app testing yields real-time data accuracy
6. The app should offer access control through encryption-decryption

If you have already worked over these factors planning the test automation of your mobile app in IoT, let me know what exactly you are looking for further. Is it defining the process to test, tools, or writing use cases?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach should be similar to testing any other system (application). Firstly make sure you have your test cases (for functionality, performance, security, etc.) ready. Given that the application is already in production, hopefully these must already be prepared. This will give you clearer picture about the QA process to be followed as the test cases will be divided into various categories based on product (mobile app, server, BT library), and further divided into sub modules.

Given that the test cases are present, now you can approach each category one by one and check the automation feasibility for them. This can be followed by actual automation for the specific tests. This will be help you focus on the specific needs of each category rather than having the daunting task of creating a general automation framework for the whole system. As your automation code-base will increase, please make sure that there is regular refactoring followed. Also, make sure to keep track of your automation coverage.

Its better to focus initially on of the aspects of quality assurance services, (that is functional, security, performance), and then scale as manageable. The following links might be useful,

https://blog.qasource.com/iot-best-iot-testing-tools-strategies-and-products

https://blog.qasource.com/benefits-of-iot-automation-testing

https://blog.qasource.com/api-testing-and-the-internet-of-things